# Oracle: ORA-00942: "table or view does not exist" in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-sql-developer

in SQL Developer when i get session information he return me this error message: (ORA-00942: "table or view does not exist"). Can i resolve this with add grant to privilege of my user? Wich command use for wich table or view system?
Best Regards to all.
Fabio.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Could you provide us with a little bit more information? Are you connecting with `SYS as SYSDBA` when opening the connection? What do you mean when you write _"...when I get session information..."_? Hit the [edit] button an add as much details as possible to your question. This could be a possible duplicate of [ORA-00942: table or view does not exist- Can it be solved by granting privileges to user?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/134290/15356).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

SQL Developer runs the below query (which you can check by clicking the Run Report in SQL Worksheet button) for its session browser:

```
with vs as (select rownum rnum,
                            inst_id,
                            sid,
                            serial#,
                            status,
                            username,
                            last_call_et,
                            command,
                            machine,
                            osuser,
                            module,
                            action,
                            resource_consumer_group,
                            client_info,
                            client_identifier,
                            type,
                            terminal,
                            sql_id,
                            sql_child_number
                       from gv$session) 
           select vs.inst_id, vs.sid ,serial# serial, vs.sql_id, vs.sql_child_number,
                  vs.username "Username",
                  case when vs.status = 'ACTIVE' 
                            then last_call_et 
                       else null end "Seconds in Wait",
                  (select command_name from v$sqlcommand where command_type = vs.command ) "Command",
                  vs.machine "Machine",
                  vs.osuser "OS User", 
                  lower(vs.status) "Status",
                  vs.module "Module",
                  vs.action "Action",
                  vs.resource_consumer_group,
                  vs.client_info,
                  vs.client_identifier
             from vs 
            where vs.USERNAME is not null
              and nvl(vs.osuser,'x') <> 'SYSTEM'
              and vs.type <> 'BACKGROUND'
              order by 1,2,3
```

Based on that, grants needed:

```
grant select on sys.gv_$session to your_user;
grant select on sys.v_$sqlcommand to your_user;
```

You may need additional privileges for other options.

Comment: Hi Balazs Papp, into the SQL Developer i can't recover the sql statment, also following your indication (...which you can check by clicking the Run Report in SQL Worksheet button...).